# navigation between pages in STS

Tags: spring, spring-mvc, navigation

I'm trying to do simple navigation between two pages, but an error appears and i can not solve it

firt page is my `home.jsp` here i make a link

```
<a href="/timecard/NewAccount"><FONT COLOR="#40C0FF">Create New Account</FONT></a>
```

then i make accounts folder i witch i have to files `createAccount.jsp` - this is my target page, and `views.xml` whit this source

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="no"?>
<!DOCTYPE tiles-definitions PUBLIC "-//Apache Software Foundation//DTD Tiles Configuration 2.1//EN" "http://tiles.apache.org/dtds/tiles-config_2_1.dtd">
<tiles-definitions>
<definition extends="default" name="createNew">
<put-attribute name="body" value="/WEB-INF/views/accounts/createAccount.jsp"/>
</definition>

</tiles-definitions>
```

And my `AccountsController`

```
@Controller
@RequestMapping(value="/timecard/newAccounts")
public class AccountsController {


@RequestMapping(method=RequestMethod.GET)
public String accountForm(Model model){

    return "createNew";
}

}
```

So when i click the link in `home.jsp` the page is not found and this is the message

`WARN : org.springframework.web.servlet.PageNotFound - No mapping found for HTTP request with URI [/timecard/NewAccount] in DispatcherServlet with name 'appServlet'`

i'm really confused. can you tell me what i'm doing wrong.
thanks in advance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are using wrong url in href tag. In your controller you have mapped url `/timecard/newAccounts`.

So you need to change the href to `${pageContext.servletContext.contextPath}/timecard/newAccounts` and then try again.

Hope this helps you. Cheers.

Comment: `<definition extends="default" name="createNew">
<put-attribute name="body" value="/WEB-INF/views/accounts/createAccount.jsp"/>`

Comment: Not this. In your dispatcher-servlet.xml file where you must be having ViewResolver configuration done for tiles. I want to see that.